# linking a checkbox to criteria stored in another table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I need to create reports for students, which will specify which tasks they have not yet completed.  The report currently shows check boxes for each task and the full list of criteria whether they have completed the task or not.  If the task has not been done, then I want the criteria for that task which is stored in another table to show.  Likewise, if it has been done, I would not want the criteria to show.

Have played with if, combo boxes and lookups, but brain freeze has now set in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand the question, and it's not clear what the data structure is, but it seems to me that you could a subreport and use the Detail view's OnFormat event to hide/reveal the subreport.

That is, in the OnFormat event of the Detail:

```
  Me!CriteriaReport.Visible = Not (Me!TaskComplete)
```

The idea is to create a report that displays the criteria in a subreport for every task all the time, and then add this code to hide it when it's not needed.

But, of course, I may not understand enough about your data structure, so this might not work.

Comment: Many thanks!  Subreports hadn't crossed my mind - too busy trying to solve a database problem with a spreadsheet solution!!  No wonder I got nowhere.

Comment: If the requirements are all in one place, e.g., in a memo field, you could certainly avoid the subreport and just put it in your report's recordsource and then use the same approach to make it visible/hidden as needed.